# Linux: How do I find out if a file has been updated by another process?

Tags: c, linux, file

I am currently watching an XML file from log4j output. I have a custom viewer that displays the log-output in GUI. I need to watch this file as to when it gets updated so that the GUI can re-parse and update itself. In C# there is a FileWatcher concept so on Windows no-probs, but what options do i have using C on Linux.

Is there a standard way of doing this on both unix and linux flavours (POSIX maybe)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John mentioned the two main routes you can take for watching files under Unix/Linux systems: notification and polling.

**Notification** is when the system itself (usually the kernel) triggers a message to registered applications whenever the file is accessed or written to. This approach requires a compliant system and might not be available on older machines.

The primary implementation of notification under Linux is [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), which is built into kernels 2.6.13 and later and can be patched into 2.6.12 and earlier. There's a [nice IBM guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify.html) on using inotify as well as a basic [set of tools and C library](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/) for accessing inotify.

**Polling** is when your program repeatedly checks a file at intervals to see if anything about that file - its size, last modification time, owner, etc. - has been changed.

There's no standard implementation of this, as it's written on a program-level rather than system-level basis, although the system call [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) exists and seems to do something useful for this purpose (the man page says it's similar to [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), and it waits for an event to become available on a file descriptor). You could also take the more basic approach with [stat](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html) and do your checking on your own.

Comment: I doubt that poll() will help. It sounds like you have misunderstood what poll() does. Unless you mean to use it *with* inotify.

Comment: To clarify: poll() can only tell you stuff like "if I read() from this file now, will that block?" or "Wait for max 3 seconds or until I can read (without read() blocking) from at least one of these file descriptors".

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like [inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) ?

Alternatively you could poll the file using [stat](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html).

Comment: That meets my needs perfectly, but i think i will have to re-invent the wheel and code it using standard C APIs. So is there any chance that i can do it using simple fstat and stat APIs?

Comment: You might want to clarify that ... If inotify sounds like what you need, and you're on Linux, why can't you just use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more portable than inotify, which is a Linux-ism, look into the [File Alteration Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_alteration_monitor), which is older and more portable technology, but can be less performant.  On the other hand, it does something useful with NFS-mounted filesystems, which depending on your application could be important.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, particularly as it is kernel agnostic and probably works with NFS mounted systems.